# Cannot convert value of type (CMAccelerometerData!,NSError!)->() to CMAccelerometerHandler(aka(Optional<CMAccelerometerData>,Optional<NSError>)-<())

Tags: xcode, swift2

I recently **upgraded my xcode from version 6.3.1 to xcode 7.1 beta.** I am using CMMotionManger and the following code shows error in new version. I tried resolving it but could not find the solution. Thanks in Advance.

***Code:***

```
let motionManager=CMMotionManager()
        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.2
        if(motionManager.accelerometerAvailable)
        {
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: { in
            (accelerometerData: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) in
            let acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration
            self.accelerationX = CGFloat(acceleration.x)
       })
        }
```

***error Encountered:***

Cannot convert value of type '(CMAccelerometerData!,NSError!)->()'to expected argument type 'CMAccelerometerHandler'(aka'(Optional,Optional)-<()')

Comment: Got the answer. Tried out this and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer. Tried many things and the following worked.

Declare the accelerometerData,error as below and use directly the variables inside the handler block. 
    ***let _:CMAccelerometerData!

    let _:NSError!***

```
let _:CMAccelerometerData!
    let _:NSError!

    if(motionManager.accelerometerAvailable)
    {
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: {
        accelerometerData,error in
        let acceleration = accelerometerData!.acceleration
        self.accelerationX = CGFloat(acceleration.x)
   })
```

and it works.:)

Comment: If your custom type has a stored property that is logically allowed to have “no value”—perhaps because its value cannot be set during initialization, or because it is allowed to have “no value” at some later point—declare the property with an optional type. Properties of optional type are automatically initialized with a value of nil, indicating that the property is deliberately intended to have “no value yet” during initialization.